# find add or delete values between two array

Tags: php, arrays

I write a code for sync two array and know which was must delete and which was add to new array.

```
<?php
$currentArray = array('ali', 'hasan', 'husein'); //base array read from database
$saveArray = array('husein', 'Hasan', 'taghi'); //requested item for save/delete in database
$deleteArray = array();
$addArray = array();

$currentArray = array_map('strtolower', $currentArray);
$saveArray = array_map('strtolower', $saveArray);

foreach ($currentArray as $a) {
    if (!in_array($a, $saveArray))
        $deleteArray[] = $a;
}

foreach ($saveArray as $a) {
    if (!in_array($a, $currentArray))
        $addArray[] = $a;
}

echo 'must be deleted:';
var_dump($deleteArray);

echo 'must be added:';
var_dump($addArray);

?>
```

Output:

```
must be deleted:

array
  0 => string 'ali' (length=3)

must be added:

array
  0 => string 'taghi' (length=5)
```

Now, Do you thinks is it better, faster and simpler code for this action?

Comment: you want to replace taghi in the area of ali ?

Comment: @AvinashBabu, no, I want delete `ali` and add `taghi`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [**array_udiff()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php) for this, using [**strcasecmp()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php) as the callback function.

```
$currentArray = array('ali', 'hasan', 'husein');
$saveArray = array('husein', 'Hasan', 'taghi');

$deleteArray = array_udiff($currentArray, $saveArray, 'strcasecmp');

$addArray = array_udiff($saveArray, $currentArray, 'strcasecmp');
```

[**See demo**](http://codepad.org/Uv3YdCT2)

Answer (score 2):

The values must be the same.

```
$currentArray = array_map('strtolower', $currentArray);
$saveArray = array_map('strtolower', $saveArray);
```

And basically use use Array diff.

```
$deleteArray = array_diff($currentArray, $saveArray);
$addArray = array_diff($saveArray, $currentArray);
```